# How to calculate the number of strings generated by permuting the given string satisfying the below conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

**The question goes like this-**

How many strings can be generated by permuting the characters of **"abbbbcccdeff"** such that there are only 1 mismatchings and the rest 11 are same ?

**My attempt-**

In my opinion, there are no such permutations of any string whose permutation has only one mismatching with the original string. So my answer is zero.
Am I right or I am missing some corner cases?

Like suppose- **"abbbbcccdeff"** can be permuted to give -**"cbbbbaccdeff"** and thus there are two mismatches-**(a,c)** and **(c,a)**

Similarly, is there any string possible by permuting this string such that there are only one mismatch ?

Comment: What is  a "missmatch"? A different letter out of this group, a different order??

Comment: Like suppose- "abbbbcccdeff" can be permuted to give -"cbbbbaccdeff" and thus there are two mismatches-(a,c) and (c,a)...
Similarly, is there any string possible by permuting this string such that there are only one mismatch

Comment: sorry, there was a "typo". It is now corrected

Comment: With remaining  $11$ the same there are, as you saw, no such permutations.

Comment: @AndréNicolas
Thanks